# Eclipse-Oxygen fails to run Arquillian Unit tests

Tags: java, eclipse, wildfly, jboss-arquillian, eclipse-oxygen

I am trying to move a JBoss-Wildfly project from Wildfly 8.2 to Wildfly-12. The code compiles and runs fine. It uses Arquillian Unit tests, they all run find via the maven command line. 
To move to Wildfly 12 I had to upgrade to Eclipse Oxygen. I set up a new environment with a new VM and fresh install of Oxygen.3a with JBOSS-Tools 4.5.3
If I run any of the Arquillian unit tests from Eclipse, it deploys to Wildfly, but the tests all fail:

```
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: INSTANCE
at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.<clinit>(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:146)
at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.ClientHttpEngineBuilder43.build(ClientHttpEngineBuilder43.java:122)
at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.ResteasyClientBuilder.build(ResteasyClientBuilder.java:406)
at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.ResteasyClientBuilder.build(ResteasyClientBuilder.java:38)
at javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder.newClient(ClientBuilder.java:121)
at org.jboss.arquillian.extension.rest.client.RestEnricher.enrichByType(RestEnricher.java:45)
at org.jboss.arquillian.extension.rest.client.BaseRestEnricher.resolve(BaseRestEnricher.java:74)
at org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.execution.LocalTestExecuter.enrichArguments(LocalTestExecuter.java:94)
at org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.execution.LocalTestExecuter.execute(LocalTestExecuter.java:60)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:96)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:103)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:85)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:143)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:114)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventImpl.fire(EventImpl.java:67)
at org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.execution.ClientTestExecuter.execute(ClientTestExecuter.java:53)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:96)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:103)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:85)
at org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.client.ContainerEventController.createContext(ContainerEventController.java:142)
at org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.client.ContainerEventController.createTestContext(ContainerEventController.java:129)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:96)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:92)
at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.TestContextHandler.createTestContext(TestContextHandler.java:130)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:96)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:92)
at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.TestContextHandler.createClassContext(TestContextHandler.java:92)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:96)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:92)
at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.TestContextHandler.createSuiteContext(TestContextHandler.java:73)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:96)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:92)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:143)
at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.EventTestRunnerAdaptor.test(EventTestRunnerAdaptor.java:136)
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$8.evaluate(Arquillian.java:372)
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$4.evaluate(Arquillian.java:246)
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.multiExecute(Arquillian.java:431)
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.access$200(Arquillian.java:55)
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$5.evaluate(Arquillian.java:260)
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$7$1.invoke(Arquillian.java:324)
at org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.execution.ClientBeforeAfterLifecycleEventExecuter.execute(ClientBeforeAfterLifecycleEventExecuter.java:99)
at org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.execution.ClientBeforeAfterLifecycleEventExecuter.on(ClientBeforeAfterLifecycleEventExecuter.java:72)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:96)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:103)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:85)
at org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.client.ContainerEventController.createContext(ContainerEventController.java:142)
at org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.client.ContainerEventController.createBeforeContext(ContainerEventController.java:124)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:96)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:92)
at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.TestContextHandler.createTestContext(TestContextHandler.java:130)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:96)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:92)
at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.TestContextHandler.createClassContext(TestContextHandler.java:92)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:96)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:92)
at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.TestContextHandler.createSuiteContext(TestContextHandler.java:73)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:96)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:92)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:143)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:114)
at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.EventTestRunnerAdaptor.fireCustomLifecycle(EventTestRunnerAdaptor.java:159)
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$7.evaluate(Arquillian.java:317)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$2.evaluate(Arquillian.java:205)
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.multiExecute(Arquillian.java:431)
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.access$200(Arquillian.java:55)
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$3.evaluate(Arquillian.java:219)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.run(Arquillian.java:167)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:538)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:760)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:460)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:206)
```

This is specific to Eclipse Oxygen, the Wildfly 8.2 version ran fine from Eclipse Neon.3 and earlier versions. The tests run from the linux command line.
Googling this appears to be a mismatched httpclient library in the classpath. Strange that it only effects running the tests from Eclipse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked around this by upgrading to Eclipse Photon, and JBOSS Tools 4.6.0. Tests run fine with this combination